# Yet another maxAllowedContentLength question

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

We have an Asp.Net core (3.1) web site hosted in Azure and deployed using Deployment Center (Kudo/github). The project file includes a web.config as we need to set the `maxAllowedContentLength`. -However, when you run the application locally, it updates the file with `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` set to "Development".

```xml
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44390" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
      <!-- Increased content length for support of uploading images-->
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

We can of course resolve this by removing it before commiting any changes, but this step is easily forgotten and the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` will be set to "Development".

I've tried setting it in the configuration settings in the Azure Web app, but it seams to get overridden by the settings in the web.config.

So is there a way to set the `maxAllowedContentLength` programmaticly (while we would not need the web.config) or a way to override the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`?

Thank you!

Comment: You can refer to my answer to set these two configurations. In addition, the `web.config` file may not be needed. If it is added, it will take effect in the app services deployed in the windows environment, Linux has not yet tested. And if there is a setting in portal, then portal setting priority is higher than `web.config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Program.cs` file.

```
public class Program
{
    public static long MaxRequestBodySizeValue = 0;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MaxRequestBodySizeValue = 20200703;
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
                {
                    // Handle requests up to your value
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = MaxRequestBodySizeValue;
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

You can add a interface to test.

```
 public string getEnv() {
        string env = string.Empty;
        env = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        env += "  &&   MaxRequestBodySizeValue = " + Program.MaxRequestBodySizeValue;
        return env;
 }
```

Then I run in my local. I also create `web.config` file to test the value.

[image]

We can see our program running env.

[image]

Finally, I deploy it by git and test it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of working back-and-forth I finally came to a solution...

The only way I could get the upload to work was through setting maxAllowedContentLength in the web.config file. Setting MaxRequestBodySize in program.cs had no affect.

However, by updating ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (and ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT) environment variables in the Main or program.cs did the trick. These settings still automaticly get set in the web.config, but are overridden in the Main:

```cs
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if (!DEBUG)
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Production");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT", "443");
#endif
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
```